# Customize Spring @RequestParam Deserialization for Maps and/or Nested Objects

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-4, http-request-parameters

```
@RestController
class MyController {
     @RequestMapping(...)
     public void test(Container container) { ... }
}
```

Spring by default uses Dot-Notation to deserialize a nested @RequestParam:

```
class Container {
    A a;
}

class A {
    String val;
}
```

works with:

```
http://.../myController?a.val=foo
```

---

But for Maps it uses Square Bracket notation:

```
class Container {
    Map<String, String> a;
}
```

works with:

```
http://.../myController?a[val]=foo
```

---

When using JavaScript there's of course no difference between a HashMap and a Nested Object, so everything will get serialized either with Dots **or** Square-Brackets.

---

### Question:

How / where can I tell Spring (or Spring Boot if that's easier) to use Dot-Notation (or Square Brackets) for **both**, nested objects **and** Maps?

Or is there any reason why Spring makes a difference between those types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot supports the use of dot-separated paths to bind maps thanks to its custom `DataBinder` subclass, [RelaxedDataBinder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedDataBinder.java). The good news is that its also a `DataBinder` that's used in Spring MVC to perform the request parameter binding. The bad news is that plugging in your own binder isn't straightforward and that it needs to be a `WebDataBinder`. You can plug one in by declaring your own `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` bean named `requestMappingHandlerAdapter`. For example:

```
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdpter() {
    return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter() {

        @Override
        protected InitBinderDataBinderFactory createDataBinderFactory(
                List<InvocableHandlerMethod> binderMethods)
                throws Exception {
            return new ServletRequestDataBinderFactory(binderMethods, getWebBindingInitializer()) {

                @Override
                protected ServletRequestDataBinder createBinderInstance(
                        final Object target, String objectName,
                        NativeWebRequest request) {

                    return new ServletRequestDataBinder(target) {

                        private RelaxedDataBinder relaxedBinder = new RelaxedDataBinder(target);

                        @Override
                        protected void doBind(MutablePropertyValues mpvs) {
                            this.relaxedBinder.bind(mpvs);
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        }   
    };
}
```

You may well want to refactor this to avoid the use of multiple nested anonymous inner classes, but it hopefully illustrates the general approach.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. That code looks really looks like sh*t, **but it works!!** `:)`

Comment: Now I noticed, that this produces a lot of other errors `:(` Spring's `Pageable` won't work anymore, because `Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]: Specified class is an interface`. Seems like all those modules won't get registered anymore automatically by Spring Boot.

Comment: If it used `RelaxedDataBinder` then it would support case-insensitive enum conversion, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, ServletRequest request) {
    new RelaxedDataBinder(binder.getTarget()).bind(new ServletRequestParameterPropertyValues(request));
}
```

This is how I got away with it; a method in the controller delegating to a `RelaxedDataBinder`.